# Snapshot of one model to another using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models: Project, MonthlySubscription (sti of Subscription), and MonthlyTransactionQueue (sti of TransactionQueue). Subscription and TransactionQueue both `belong_to` Project.

I want to create a copy of MonthlySubscription and place it into MonthlyTransactionQueue, for Projects that have a Release.released = false. How would I do this using AR?

My sql looks like this:

```
insert into transaction_queues
select a.*, b.id as release_id
 from subscriptions a
 left join releases b
  on a.project_id = b.project_id
 where b.released = false
 and a.type = 'ReleaseSubscription'
```

For AR I have started with this `ReleaseSubscription.joins(project: :releases)` but it doesn't keep the Release.released field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options

1. Execute sql 
   ReleaseSubscription.connection.execute("insert into transaction_queues...")
2. Use AR inside of a transaction.

   ```
   MonthlyTransactionQueue.transaction do
    # I'm unsure what Release.released is and how it relates but this should work other than that.
     MonthlySubscription.where(released: false).each do |sub| 
      MonthlyTransactionQueue.create(sub.attributes)
    end
   end
   ```

   This creates multiple insert statements but runs them all in the same transaction.
3. Another good option would be to dump everything that matches your query into a sql file and use `load data in file` to add everything at once in sql.

Comment: Thanks Isaac. For `MonthlySubscription.where(released: false)`, the released field is in the Release model, so I think I need something like `MonthlySubscription.joins(Release.where(released: false))`?

Comment: Replace `MonthlySubscription.where(released: false).each do |sub| ` with `MonthlySubscription.joins(:releases).where(releases: {released: false}).each do |sub|`